# Anaconda pip vs native Ubuntu pip

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have an installation of Ubuntu 14.04, which comes with Python 2.7 by default. If I were to install a Python package "foo", I would normally run `pip install foo`. The `pip` executable is found in `/usr/bin`.

However, I have now installed Anaconda, and I want to use this as my default Python interpreter. This means that when I run `pip install foo`, I want it to call Anaconda's `pip`, rather than the `pip` that comes with Ubuntu. In this way, installing a new package will copy it to Anaconda's `site-packages` directory, rather than that of the native Python installation.

Now, in my `.bashrc` file, I added `export PATH=/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/Anaconda/bin:$PATH`, and in that path is Anaconda's `pip`. However, this means there now exist two `pip` executables on `PATH`. How can I ensure that one which is called is that within the Anaconda distribution?

Comment: $PATH is evaluated left->right. if you have `PATH=dir1;dir2;dir3`, and a some binary file that exists in all three of those dirs, then the one in `dir1` will be used, since it's the first scanned/tested/used.

Comment: Why not call `conda install foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I ensure that one which is called is that within the Anaconda distribution

Executables on the PATH are inspected from left-to-right.

```
PATH=/home/karnivaurus/Libraries/Anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

Will now **always** use the Anaconda binaries if present.

If you would like to use the native `pip`, then you will need to qualify its path like so

```
/usr/bin/pip --version
```